# How to connect python with mysql database using pyodbc API?

Tags: python, mysql, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc

driver='{MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver}'
server='localhost'
database='python'
username='root'
password='PASSSWORD'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Driver='{MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver}',Server=server,Database=database,Uid=username,Pwd=password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

**When I run it gives me this error**

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(Driver='{MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI 
Driver}',Server=server,Database=database,Uid=username,Pwd=password)

pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see the names of the ODBC drivers available to your Python app. (BTW, I just tried your code and it worked fine for me.)

Comment: Thanks for replying. But when I print pyodbc.drivers() to console it does not show me any driver for MySQL.

Comment: Then you'll need to install a copy of MySQL Connector/ODBC that matches the "bitness" of your Python interpreter (32-bit or 64-bit).

Comment: Can you please tell me the steps to download a copy of  MySQL Connector/ODBC.

Comment: Just in case someone finds this question in an undefined future: you have to match bit architecture of the ODBC driver to the architecture of your operating system, eg. Win 10 32-bit goes along with 32-bit drivers (MySQL, SQL, etc). After installing such drivers  `pyodbc.drivers()` should retrieve some info of the drivers you just installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(f'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

You need to use ' symbol at the beginning and end of the whole.